# Сколько public классов может быть в одном файле?

Tags: java, классы

Изучаю Java по учебнику К.Сьерра и Б.Бейтса "Изучаем Java 2-е издание 2012", там есть пример кода программы состоящей из трёх классов, все три класса имеют приставку public, но когда я переписал код и попытался запустить, командная строка выдала что-то типа "имя вашего public-класса должно совпадать с именем файла". Так как название у файла одно, а классов целых три я предположил что public-класс может быть тоже только один. В итоге я оставил public только у того класса, где есть main. Заработало, но теперь я не знаю, был ли я прав насчет того, что в программе может быть только один public класс? Но ведь тогда это значит что в учебнике ошибка? Либо у меня какая-то другая Java, которая изменилась со времён выпуска учебника в 2012 году.
Могу приложить скрины из учебника, если понадобится.

Код пишу в Notepad++, программы запускаю через командную строку Windows, если это имеет значение.

Comment: В одном файле может быть много классов, но публичным должен быть том, что назван как файл. Остальные в этом файле - без паблик

Comment: Если вы про три класса на 69 -70 странице,  то в конце 68-ой страницы написано: Классы: GuessGame.class , Player.class , GameLancher.class - подразумевается, что это три файла, но акцент на этом не делается и новичку может быть непонятно, согласен.

Comment: Я такое встречал , читая книги. Я не знаю что хотел этим сказать автор . Скорее всего то , что каждый класс находится в отдельном файле.

Comment: @pavlofff именно про них. Не знаю, как там может подразумеваться три файла, до этого момента читателя за ручку ведут начиная с самых азов, и я не помню чтобы там вообще учили запускать программу, состоящую из нескольких файлов. Я вот понятия не имею как это сделать. Видимо ошибка в книге все-таки.

Comment: Запускается файл, содержащий публичный метод `main()` (точку входа), остальное происходит без вашего участия, компилятор сам найдет нужные ему файлы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В одном физическом java-файле может быть только один публичный класс, имя которого должно совпадать с именем файла и любое количество вложенных классов.

Так же допускается в одном физическом файле размещать вместе с public-классом  отдельные не вложенные классы с уровнем доступа `default/package/private`, но так делать не рекомендуется.

В программе на Java может быт любое количество физических java-файлов, каждый из которых может содержать публичный класс. Все эти классы могут вызываться напрямую из любого другого класса, если находятся в одной области видимости (или через импорт, если в разных областях).

Comment: "с уровнем доступа private" - у top level класса может быть только public или package-private (без модификатора доступа)

Comment: @Russtam Да, я имел ввиду, что вместе с public-классом могут быт приватные, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Уточните, какие из этих ограничений жестко прописаны в стандарте и проверяются средой, а какие просто правила хорошего тона?

Comment: @Kromster то, где написано, что допускается, но не рекомендуется, то компилятор пропустит, но делать так не принято, а остальное не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Kromster да, компилятор выдаст предупреждение о ошибке, если будет более одного публичного класса (читайте вопрос), так же выдаст предупреждение, если имена файла и публичного класса не будут совпадать. Если разработка ведется в IDE, то  она так же сразу отметит ошибку еще до начала компиляции. Компиляция с такой ошибкой будет невозможна до устранения.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, в книге подразумевалось, что все эти три класса размещаются в разных файлах.

Comment: Нет, программ с несколькими файлами ещё не давалось. Я вообще почти в начале книги.

Comment: @KirovReporting Это в Java само собой разумеется. Предлагаю сравнить с текстом оригинала книги.

Comment: Нашёл оригинал, там точно такой же код, вот, можете сами взглянуть, страницы 39-40. http://www.opus-college.net/devcorner/HeadFirstJava2ndEdition.pdf