# В классе Main выбивает ошибку "The public type Main must be defined in its own file"

Tags: java

```
package app;

public class Museum1 {
private static int visitorsSum;
private String country, city, address;
private double rating;
private int visitors;



/**
* Empty constructor
 * @return 
*/

Museum1() {
}

/**
* Constructor with parameters (4 vars)
*
* @param country The country where the Museum
* @param city The city where the Museum
* @param address The address where the Museum
* @param rating The rating where the Museum
*/
Museum1(String country, String city, String address, double rating) {
this.country = country;
this.city = city;
this.address = address;
this.rating = rating;
}

/**
* Constructor with parameters (all vars)
*
* @param country The country where the Museum
* @param city The city where the Museum
* @param address The address where the Museum
* @param rating The rating where the Museum
* @param visitors The number of visitors
*/
Museum1(String country, String city, String address, double rating, int visitors) {
this.country = country;
this.city = city;
this.address = address;
this.rating = rating;
this.visitors = visitors;

setVisitorsSum(visitors);
}

/**
* Setters block
*/
public void setCountry(String country) {
this.country = country;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

public void setRating(double rating) {
this.rating = rating;
}

public void setVisitors(int visitors) {
this.visitors = visitors;
}

private static void setVisitorsSum(int visitorsSum) {
Museum1.visitorsSum += visitorsSum;
}

/**
* Getters block
*/
public String getCountry() {
return country;
}

public String getCity() {
return city;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public double getRating() {
return rating;
}

public int getVisitors() {
return visitors;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Museum{" +
"country='" + country + '\'' +
", city='" + city + '\'' +
", address='" + address + '\'' +
", rating=" + rating +
", visitors=" + visitors +
'}';
}

/**
* Displays the number of all visitors
*/
static void printStaticSum() {
System.out.println("Кількість відвідувачів за весь час: " + visitorsSum);
}

/**
* Displays the number of all visitors
*/
void printSum() {
System.out.println("Кількість відвідувачів за весь час: " + visitorsSum);
}

/**
* Changes values of variables
*
* @param country The country where the Museum
* @param city The city where the Museum
* @param address The address where the Museum
* @param rating The rating where the Museum
* @param visitors The number of visitors
*/
void resetValues(String country, String city, String address, double rating, int visitors) {
this.country = country;
this.city = city;
this.address = address;
this.rating = rating;
this.visitors = visitors;
}
}

public class Main {
//тут
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Initializing objects
Museum1 arsenal = new Museum1();
Museum1 pharmacy = new Museum1("Ukraine", "Lviv", "Stavropigijska, 3", 4.5);
Museum1 andreja = new Museum1("Ukraine", "Lviv", "Runok, 6", 5.0, 50);

//Displays information on the screen
System.out.println(arsenal.toString());
System.out.println(pharmacy.toString());
System.out.println(andreja.toString());

System.out.println();

Museum1.printStaticSum();
andreja.printSum();
}
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Публичный класс Main должен быть в собственном файле - это написано прямо в ошибке человеческим языком, почему бы не попытаться прочитать, что хочет сказать вам компилятор о своих проблемах с вашим кодом.

Эта ошибка значит, что в Java каждый публичный класс должен быть в отдельном файле, а имя файла соответствовать имени класса. В одном файле с публичным классом может быть только  приватный класс или вложенный класс

Связанный вопрос: ["Сколько публичных классов может быть в одном файле"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/532188/177345)

Answer (score 0):

Собственно ответ прост, нельзя в одном файле размещать два внешних public класса.
Разбейте свой код на два файла (в каждом по классе) и эта ошибка исчезнет.

Comment: В одном файле можно размешать несколько классов, только `public` должен быть один (тот, который соответствует названию файла).

Comment: @post_zeew не совсем верно, `public` классов может быть сколько угодно, если они `inner` или `nested`, а public класс "верхнего" уровня может быть только один

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, Согласен. Я имел ввиду top-level classes.

Comment: Согласен, зашел свой вопрос разместить и увидил этот не много странный вопрос...